# Camel POST RestService accepting JSONArray : annotations and parsing errors

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

I'm trying to build an Apache Camel (v2.15) route to handle a POST request on a REST service.

The expected POST requests will look like this (a JSONArray representing a list of JSONObjects that are all instances of a single given type):

```js
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

[
    {
        "aaa": "TEST",
        "bbb": "TEST",
        "ccc": 5004000
    },
    {
        "aaa": "TEXT",
        "bbb": "TEXT",
        "ccc": 5004001
    },
    ...
]
```

**My problem is to configure things to get the POST body correctly unserialized...**

Here is the route definition:

```java
from("cxfrs:bean:messageServer").choice()
        .when(header("operationName").isEqualTo("postJsonMessage"))
        .beanRef("messageService", "postJsonMessage")
        .end();
```

Now, the service definition that is referenced via the beanRef line:

```java
@Path("/root-path/")
public class MyService {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

    @POST
    @Path("/message/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
    public void postJsonMessage(@Body final List<CustomMessage> data) {
        logger.info("body size :" + data.size());
    }
}
```

And the POJO that describes the items of the unserialized list:

```java
public class CustomMessage {
    private String aaa;
    private String bbb;
    private int ccc;

    // ...getters and setters...
}
```

When I use no annotation on the POJO, I got this exception:

```
JAXRSUtils | 152 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-core - 3.0.6 | No message body reader has been found for class java.util.List, ContentType: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

But if I use the **@XMLRootElement** on the POJO, I got a JSON parsing exception:

```
AbstractJAXBProvider | 152 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-core - 3.0.6 | javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[0,1] Message: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [
    {
        "aaa": "TEST",
        "bbb": "TEST",
        "ccc": 5004000
    },
    ...
```

**So how can I configure the parser to interpret the posted data as a JSONArray and not as a JSONObject?**

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, a solution was found to my problem, by using `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` and an array type definition for the `@Body` parameter:

So, in the `camel-context.xml` we have defined a provider and installed the associated libraries in the osgi:

```xml
<cxf:rsServer id="messageServer"
    address="http://0.0.0.0:${rest.service.message.port}"
    serviceClass="com.example.service.MyService">
    <cxf:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsServer>
```

The required libraries were (in our environment):

```sh
install mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.12
install mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.12
install mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.12
install mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.12
```

Then, the service method signature was modified to expect an array of `CustomMessage` objects:

```java
    @POST
    @Path("/message/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
    public void postJsonMessage(@Body final CustomMessage[] data) {
        // process data...
    }
```

Also, the type definition was added in the route builder:

```java
    from("cxfrs:bean:messageServer").choice()
            .when(header("operationName").isEqualTo("postJsonMessage"))
            .convertBodyTo(CustomMessage[].class)
            .beanRef("messageService", "postJsonMessage")
            .end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember to have faced a similar issue (but with marshalling).
The workaround was to define a wrapper around the list, so that the Jackson lib will now be able to unmarshall your JSON payload

```
public class CustomMessageList extends ArrayList<CustomMessage> {};

@POST
@Path("/message/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public void postJsonMessage(@Body final CustomMessageList data) {
   logger.info("body size :" + data.size());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I couldn't get it working as is, but it was a good hint to try changing things in the type definition for the @Body parameter...